# How to use user profile fields location fields in a rules component?

Tags: rules, users, location

I have a case where users will register with the site from foreign countries. I'd like to be able to let the admin know to update the geocoding settings for the country that they register from.

I'm working with [rules](https://www.drupal.org/project/rules), location and User-location, and Gmap. What I have so far is this:

```
{ "rules_email_admin_update_geocoding_" : {
    "LABEL" : "Email Admin to update Geocoding",
    "PLUGIN" : "reaction rule",
    "OWNER" : "rules",
    "REQUIRES" : [ "rules" ],
    "ON" : { "user_insert" : [] },
    "IF" : [
      { "entity_has_field" : { "entity" : [ "site:current-user" ], "field" : "field_location_opt_out" } },
      { "AND" : [
          { "data_is" : { "data" : [ "site:current-user:field-location-opt-out" ], "value" : "0" } }
        ]
      }
    ],
    "DO" : [
      { "component_rules_send_email_to_admin" : {
          "subject" : "Update Geocoding Configuration ",
          "body" : "A new user [site:current-user] has registered with location information, check to see if the user\u0027s address is outside of the US and if the geocoding settings need to be updated to show the user on the map. Go to admin\/config\/content\/location\/geocoding and see if their country is configure. ",
          "from" : "admin@phisigmarho.org"
        }
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

This sends an email to the admin when the location-opt-out field is false, that is that the user entered location information. The issue is that I can't drill any further into the location information than the fact that the user hasn't opted out. This works ok for new users, but I will need to have another rule when a registered user updates their address. This leaves me with a problem, because I can't check the actual values in the locations fields.

So, what's the next step? can I access those values with a php snippet, and if so, how?

UPDATE: So, this appears to be an issue with how Rules interacts with the Fields API.[Rules Fields](https://www.drupal.org/node/1995880)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Install [Countries](https://www.drupal.org/project/countries) module add field in your registration page.
when user register you can value of its location by selecting user country use this value in rules

Comment: Thanks Adi, will this make me add another field? or will this tie in with the user-location field? I would want to avoid redundancy.